# android periodically repeating alarm not working

Tags: android, alarm, android-alarms, periodic-task

I am trying to set periodically alarm every 30 minutes, but i dont think it is working. I use below code:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Alarm.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

long selectedTimeMiliseconds = (long) (TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(30));
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), selectedTimeMiliseconds, alarmIntent);
```

How to set the second parameter in method setInexactRepeating? Is it better to use setRepeating method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), selectedTimeMiliseconds, alarmIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Inexact is a save battery method, but it is... inexact.

AlarmManager have a problem, if the device is in sleep mode, the intent not start. You should use WakefulBroadCast.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html